# What does an empty javascript link mean?

Tags: javascript

I inspected the inbox link in hotmail using firebug and saw something like that:

```
<a ... href="javascript:; .... />
```

I just can't figure out how the postback is realizing when I click the link. And what does  "javascript:;" mean while it doesn't refer to any function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `javascript:` part there is a pseudo-protocol meaning that the URI should be interpreted as JavaScript code. The `;` immediately after it is a statement terminator. Assuming that nothing else follows, it basically makes the link do nothing when clicked.

If something is happening when the link is clicked, I'm guessing a `click` event handler has been attached to it or one of its ancestor elements. `click` bubbles up the DOM, so you don't have to watch it actually on the element itself.

You won't necessarily see those event handler attachments in the HTML; the page may well use unobtrusive techniques to hook up the handler later.

[Gratuitous live example #1](http://jsbin.com/izebi3) (hooking the `click` on the link unobtrusively)

[Gratuitous live example #2](http://jsbin.com/izebi3/2) (hooking the `click` on an ancestor element)

Answer (score 2):

It's evaluating the expression `;`, which doesn't do anything.  It's just there so that there's *something* in the `href` (otherwise it won't behave like a link).

The actual behavior is being wired-up somewhere else.  For example, it might be wireup up with something like this jQuery statement: `$('#inboxLink').click(goToInboxFunction)`

Or, as [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563127/what-does-an-empty-javascript-link-mean/4563149#4563149) points out, the `click` handler could be wired-up higher up in the DOM and use event bubbling the capture it for this link.